# how to extract string using Bigquery regexp_extract

Tags: google-bigquery

text that I am trying to parse

> Text: sometext herex0D Name: Davidx0D some more text: x0D - value1x0D - google maps to find x0D x0D What you did: x0D - i did some stuff x0D

The text I want to extract is anything after

> What you did:

So the result should be

> x0D - i did some stuff x0D

This is what I have but it is not returning what I want.

> select REGEXP_EXTRACT('Text: sometext herex0D Name: Davidx0D some more text: x0D - value1x0D - google maps to find x0D x0D What you did: x0D - i did some stuff x0D', r"What you did:(.*)")

But, if you run this as-is it will return the right result because I pasted the string in query. But if I replace the string with the column name in the table then it doesn't work. I only get

> x0D

back

Comment: works for me with column. something with the data itself - can you compare length of typed string vs. that string in table?

Comment: Length is different by 2. Length by using column name comes out to 2 more.

Comment: so this would be a key for addressing the issue I think. can you determine what those are? this would explain effect you see

Comment: I see a newline after ```did: x0D```

Comment: so that would totally explain your current result - right? just adjust you query to replace (in result) newline to space for example

Comment: or even more easy  - see my answer below

Comment: regexp_extract still not working but substr does. Thanks. Marking this as an answer but do you know why regex_extract is not working.

Comment: see update in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT ''''Text: sometext herex0D Name: Davidx0D some more text: x0D - value1x0D - google maps to find x0D x0D What you did: x0D
  i did some stuff x0D''' str
)
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(str, r"What you did:(.*)") result,
  SUBSTR(str, STRPOS(str, "What you did:") + LENGTH("What you did:")) adjusted_result
FROM `project.dataset.table`

Row     result      adjusted_result  
1       x0D         x0D i did some stuff x0D
```

> Update

So, in your table you have strings with new line that needs to be considered during the regexp parsing

By default `.` does not match `\n`
To make it work you need to use flag `s` like below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT ''''Text: sometext herex0D Name: Davidx0D some more text: x0D - value1x0D - google maps to find x0D x0D What you did: x0D
  i did some stuff x0D''' str
)
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(str, r"What you did:(.*)") result,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(str, r"(?s)What you did:(.*)") multiline_result
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row     result      multiline_result     
1       x0D         x0D i did some stuff x0D
```